# How could I disallow external connections to dockerized mysql?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The mysql server is running on top of docker with Ubuntu OS.
I only want to allow the DB connections from the Ubuntu host machine and disallow all connecitons from the rest of world for the security reason.

Comment: Just do not expose the port to the world then only containers inside your Docker network can connect to your mysql container

Comment: What if the web server is not running inside docker? But they are both running on the same VPS server?

Comment: No matter where web server run on, if your mysql container not expose the port to the outside then other place can't access to it. You can try to access to the container from your host OS (which running Docker). If you also want to make sure your server is protected then you can use `ufw` or `fail2ban` to establish the firewall and only allow incoming requests to your web server ports only.

Comment: `docker run -it  -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -name db mysql:latest`?